# Can I write a class within an ASP.NET site without compiling a DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation

I'm writing a small website using ASP.NET, writing the C# into the .aspx file directly without using code-behind or compiling a DLL. I do this mainly to allow small edits with just a text editor without having to keep going back to Visual Studio.

This is working great, except I want to write a class for some code that will be used by multiple .aspx pages. Is there a way I can add a .cs file in the same way I have C# code in .aspx files?

Comment: If you use website, you don't need to compile it in dll

Comment: Even if you are in a web site, if you add a c# class, you must build it. If you don't want to use visual studio, you can do this using Command line.           https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

I assume you have a "Web Site" in Visual Studio. If not then perhaps you should invest the time to create a new Web Site and migrate the pages into it. Then publish it and that will make things easier. The problem you describe here will be solved plus other things. If you modify the web site outside of Visual Studio however then that would probably be a problem too. I am a beginner but you probably can open the site live for editing directly. I am not sure.

I was curious about how to do what you are asking so I explored.

Anyway, assuming you already have a Web Site in Visual Studio, use "WebSite" | "Add New Item" to add a class. VS will ask you if you want to create an APP_CODE, say yes. The cs file won't have a namespace, the class will be in the global namespace.

When I got that far I was able to use VS to test a page using the class. When I copied the source, IIS said it could not find the class. So be sure that the APP_CODE directory is in the root of the web site. That probably is not enough so we will continue.

I published the web site. The published web site worked, it found the class. I could not figure out what the difference is between the published site and what I copied over. So I studied the output of the publish and I see it is creating virtual directories and adding ACLs.

I think this is the trick. First be sure the APP_CODE directory is in the root of the web site. Then go into the IIS Manager and find the web site. Right-click and select "**Convert to application**". When I did that the files that I just copied worked.

If you publish the site using Visual Studio then it will do that for you. You only need to do it once.

I tried a few other things so there might be something else I did that is necessary but I do not think so.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have an experiment. Alas, I use a shared-host service and they only give me an FTP folder rather than access to IIS. The main reason I want to have the C# code on the server is that I don't have VS everywhere. This is a quick&dirty web site set up for a technical but not-programming friend. There are comments in the C# with directions on how make future customizations.

Comment: That did the trick. I created a folder named App_Code in the website root folder and dropped some .cs files in there. The C# in the ASPX files were able to call and interact with the classes happily. Thanks!

Comment: Good. Most hosting services, such as GoDaddy, provide FTP access. It took me a long time to understand that FTP is normal. Front Page Extensions is archaic and we don't need anything like that. There is usually a control panel of some type to allow us to modify IIS in whatever ways apply to our site.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the following at the top of your .aspx file -

```
<%@ Import namespace = "mydll" %>
```

This will ensure that the class is accessible in the mark-up, assuming the methods and properties etc are setup to be so.

Any changes to the dll will still require you to edit and build in VS however.